# How to find anagram frequency in a string?

Tags: algorithm, anagram

Given a string value of arbitrary length, you're supposed to determine the frequency of words which are anagrams of each other.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> generateAnagramFrequency(String str)
{ ... }
```

For example: if the string is "find art in a rat for cart and dna trac"
your output should be a map:
    find -> 1
    art -> 2
    in -> 1
    a -> 1
    cart -> 2
    and -> 2

The keys should be the first occurrence of the word, and the number is the number of anagrams of that word, including itself.

The solution i came up with so for is to sort all the words and compare each character from both strings till the end of either strings. It would be O(logn). I am looking for some other efficient method which doesn't change the 2 strings being compared. Thanks.

Comment: It really looks a lot like homework.  You could start by telling us your unsuccessful approach/es.

Comment: @belisarius I've updated the question with my solution. Please remove the down vote so that i can ask questions. i'm banned from asking questions now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a JavaScript implementation of creation a n-gram (word analysis), at [Extract keyphrases from text (1-4 word ngrams)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085454/extract-keyphrases-from-text-1-4-word-ngrams/7451243#7451243).

This function can easily be altered to analyse the frequency of anagrams:
Replace `s = text[i];` by `s = text[i].sort()`, so that the order of characters doesn't matter any more.

Answer (score 1):

Create a "signature" for each word by sorting its letters alphabetically. Sort the words by their signatures. Run through the sorted list in order; if the signature is the same as the previous signature, you have an anagram.